# Fegin Hystrix does not effective

Tags: java, spring, hystrix, feign

I tried Feign to configure Hystrix. Enter 127.0.0.1:8100/test in the browser address bar. No matter whether it is configured with fallback or fallbackFactory, the result of the prompt is: "com.netflix.client.ClientException: Load balancer does not have available server for client: microservice-provider-user", this Explain that fallback is not working.

Controller

```
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
@RestController
public class TestController {

    private UserFeignClient userFeignClient;

    private UserFeignClient adminFeignClient;

    @Autowired
    public TestController(Decoder decoder, Encoder encoder, Client client, Contract contract) {
        this.userFeignClient = Feign.builder().client(client).encoder(encoder)
                .decoder(decoder).contract(contract)
                .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("user", "user"))
                .target(UserFeignClient.class, "http://microservice-provider-user/");

        this.adminFeignClient = Feign.builder().client(client).encoder(encoder)
                .decoder(decoder).contract(contract)
                .requestInterceptor(new BasicAuthRequestInterceptor("admin", "admin"))
                .target(UserFeignClient.class, "http://microservice-provider-user/");
    }

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        return userFeignClient.findById(123L);
    }

    @GetMapping("/testAdmin")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test2() {
        return adminFeignClient.findById(123L);
    }
}
```

Main method

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableFeignClients
@EnableHystrixDashboard
@EnableHystrix
@EnableCircuitBreaker
public class Demo2Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Demo2Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

fallback

```
@Component
public class FeignClientFallback implements UserFeignClient{
    @Override
    public String findById(Long id) {
        return "hello FeignClientFallback";
    }
}
```

gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.1.3.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

ext {
    set('springCloudServicesVersion', '2.1.2.RELEASE')
    set('springCloudVersion', 'Greenwich.SR1')
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-hystrix-dashboard'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-turbine'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-openfeign'
    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "io.pivotal.spring.cloud:spring-cloud-services-dependencies:${springCloudServicesVersion}"
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}
```

Feign client

```
@FeignClient(name = "microservice-provider-user", fallback = FeignClientFallback.class)
public interface UserFeignClient {

    @GetMapping("/test2/{id}")
    String findById(@PathVariable("id") Long id);
}
```

application.yml

```
spring:
  application:
    name: microservice-custom
eureka:
  client:
    serviceUrl:
      defaultZone: http://localhost:8761/eureka/,http://localhost:8762/eureka/
    healthcheck:
      enabled: true
  instance:
    prefer-ip-address: true

server:
  port: 8100

feign:
  hystrix:
    enabled: true
  client:
    config:
      default:
        connectTimeout: 1000
        readTimeout: 1000
        loggerLevel: basic

hystrix:
  command:
    default:
      execution:
        isolation:
          strategy: SEMAPHORE

logging:
  level:
    com.lv.springCloudClient1.UserFeignClient: DEBUG

management:
  endpoints:
    web:
      exposure:
        include: '*'
```

In theory, if I turn off the "microservice-provider-user" server, I will get the content returned by the fallback method.

Comment: Confirm whether eureka server has a service with name ```microservice-provider-user``` shown. Provide full logs

Comment: eureka server page only display ```MICROSERVICE-CUSTOMX n/a (1) (1) UP (1) - 192.168.2.31:microservice-customx:8100```  because microservice-provider-user has been shut down

Comment: ok so thats why it is throwing error, try to bring it up and test whether it works.

Comment: But the result I expect is the return value of the ```findById``` method in the ```FeignClientFallback``` class. In theory, I shut down the ```microservice-provider-user``` service. The return value should not be ```Load balancer does not have available server for client```. Isn't it?

Comment: Confused. You created feign clients manually using java DSL that could be the reason advise is not working

Comment: I tried using @AutoWired to create feign, without manually, it works.  I will check the next problem about manually create feign clients myself. thanks! 谢谢。

Comment: @Ivqiang is correct.  In order to get the automatic fallback handling when using Spring, you need to register the FeignClients as Beans and inject them into your service classes.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Import(FeignClientsConfiguration.class)
@RestController
public class TestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserFeignClient userFeignClient;

    @Autowired
    private UserFeignClient adminFeignClient;

    @GetMapping("/test")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test() {
        return userFeignClient.findById(123L);
    }

    @GetMapping("/testAdmin")
    @ResponseBody
    public String test2() {
        return adminFeignClient.findById(123L);
    }
}
```

I changed the previous controller code to the current one.
the Hystrix fallback method is effective.